# Force Cloudinary URLs to use HTTPS

Tags: https, cloudinary, keystonejs

I am trying to figure out how to force Cloudinary to use HTTPS in Keystone.

Tried using {{cloudinaryUrl image width=500 height=500 crop=‘fill’ secure=‘true’}} in the actual post.hbs page but no luck.

I've seen mention of this but cannot figure out which file the person is referring to.

[image: cloudinary config]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are serving your page in http but you want to force cloudinary to https, you can set the option in the keystone.init function : 'cloudinary secure': true,

This option is mapped on cloudinary options described [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_additional_topics#configuration_options)

```
keystone.init({
    'name': 'xyz',
    ...
    'cloudinary secure': true,
    ....
```

Turning on this option changes http to https the protocol when you print an src image like this :

```
src=post._.image.src({dpr:'auto'}) // pug syntax
```

Comment: Correct, that's what I ended up doing. 

 'wysiwyg cloudinary images': true,
 'cloudinary secure':true